# How do I normalize these raw numbers in my table so I can run a chi-square test?

Tags: r, normalization

Here's what we've done to run a chi-square in the raw data in r. Now how can I normalize these numbers? I've got two words ("bem" and "muito") that appear a certain number of times ($word) each century ($Century), as we can see in the code and table below. What I want to do is run the same chi-square test on these variables, but with normalized/log-transformed numbers.

```
Table3 <-xtabs(~ l50$word + l50$Century, data = l50); Table3
```

```
        l50$Century
l50$word  15  16  17  18  19
   bem     8  64  85 109  48
   muito  43 510 454 359 230
```

```
chisq.test(CenturyWordTable3)
```

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  Table3
X-squared = 28.018, df = 4, p-value = 1.237e-05

Tkx

Comment: The question isn't very clear as to what you need. Please provide a sample of your data so that we can reproduce your results and help answer your question.

Comment: Pearson's Chi-squared test as implemented in `chisq.test` is designed for tables of counts.  As the docs say, "The entries of x must be non-negative integers."  It doesn't really make sense to normalize or log-transform them.